# String to Arrays conversion

Tags: c#, arrays, character

When this is valid:

```
string s4 = "H e l l o";

string[] arr = s4.Split(new char[] { ' ' });        
foreach (string c in arr)
{
    System.Console.Write(c);  
}
```

Why This is invalid

```
string s4 = "H e l l o";

char[] arr = s4.Split(new char[] { ' ' });        
foreach (char c in arr)
{
    System.Console.Write(c);  
}
```

Cant We build a Character Array with Splitter method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intention by saying

```
char[] arr = s4.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
```

is to tell the compiler much more than he knows, that the parts after the split will be each one character long and you want to convert them to char. Why don't you tell him  explicitly, e.g. by saying

`char[] arr = s4.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Select(c => c[0]).ToArray();`

Comment: +1, but I'd also point out that it's `Split(params char[])` so you can just say `s4.Split(' ').Select(c=> c[0]).ToArray()`

Comment: So using LINQ we can explicitly guide compiler, That's nice.

Answer (score 4):

`char` is not a subtype of `string`, to start with. So, because string.Split returns an array of strings, it's not an array of char, even if every string is of length 1.

Answer (score 2):

Split method returns string[], not char[]. even if the length of each string is 1.

You can use String.toCharArray() if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

> Why This is invalid

Because `Split` returns `string[]` and not `char[]`

> Cant We build a Character Array with
>   Splitter method.

Refer to Thomas' answer (using linq)

Thanks